# rxjs switchMap and nested observables

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I want to ask my firestore for an array of documents which are holding information referencing to other documents.

get "user" document => returns ids of "items" documents => foreach(get "item" document)

```
getUserOwnedItems(uid:string):Observable<Item[]>{
    return this.firestore
          .collection<any>(`members`, ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid))
          .valueChanges()
          .pipe(
            switchMap(ids => { // these ids are representing the "item" ids 
              return ids.map(id => {
                return this.firestore
                  .doc<Item>(`items/${id.itemId}`)
                  .valueChanges();
              });
            })
            ,concatAll() // <-- Iam not sure about this
          );
}
```

The problem is Iam expecting an observable with an Array of Items. Instead I get a observable of Item back.

How can I convert this to

```
Observable<Item[]>
```

?
Thanks in advance!

My Structure in firestore looks as follows:

```
members : [
 {
  uid:string,
  itemId:string,
  ...
 }
]

items : [
 {
  id:string,
  ...
 }
]
```

The Use Case in other words:
I want to get all Items related to a specific user identified by its uid.

Update:
I found out that all concats mergs or forkJoins are not working in this scenario because the firebase observables will never be completed.

I could do something like ...

```
return this.firestore
   .doc<Item>(`items/${id.itemId}`)
   .valueChanges().pipe(first());
```

But this will break my realtime connectivity. Besides this every call of this function will result in reads on FireStore which will cost money.

Comment: Why are you using `concatAll` ?

Comment: the idea is to combine all the requests and send them back as one Observable.

Comment: SwitchMap returns a single result, so you actually have a single result.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use `combineAll` instead of `concatAll` if you need an `Observable<Item[]>`.

### combineAll

> Flattens an Observable-of-Observables by applying combineLatest when the Observable-of-Observables completes.

### concatAll

> Converts a higher-order Observable into a first-order Observable by concatenating the inner Observables in order